# Multiple filter operations on the same dataframe [Pandas]

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df as follow:

```
SN  Asset  Dept  Location  FREQ  SUN
1   A11    Mech  ACTB      M     NaN        
2   A12    Mech  CTBA      M     NaN
3   A13    Mech  CABA      Y     NaN
4   A14    Elec  ACTB      Y     NaN
5   A15    Elec  CTBA      M     NaN
6   A16    Elec  CABA      Y     NaN
7   A17    Mech  CABA      Y     NaN
8   A18    Mech  CTBA      M     NaN
9   A19    Mech  ACTB      Y     NaN
10  A20    Elec  CTBA      M     NaN
```

I need to apply a filter, having two conditions.
1) IF Dept=='Mech'
2) IF Location contain string 'CTB'
Then copy cells from FREQ to SUN.

The output should look like:

```
SN  Asset  Dept  Location  FREQ  SUN
1   A11    Mech  ACTB      M     M        
2   A12    Mech  CTBA      M     M
3   A13    Mech  CABA      Y     NaN
4   A14    Elec  ACTB      Y     NaN
5   A15    Elec  CTBA      M     NaN
6   A16    Elec  CABA      Y     NaN
7   A17    Mech  CABA      Y     NaN
8   A18    Mech  CTBA      M     M
9   A19    Mech  ACTB      Y     Y
10  A20    Elec  CTBA      M     NaN
```

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried and what's your question?

Comment: I tried nested-if statements, but those didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mask`,

```
m1 = df['Dept']=='Mech'
m2 = df['Location'].str.contains("CTB")
df['SUN'] = df['FREQ'].mask(~(m1&m2))

   SN Asset  Dept Location FREQ  SUN
0   1   A11  Mech     ACTB    M    M
1   2   A12  Mech     CTBA    M    M
2   3   A13  Mech     CABA    Y  NaN
3   4   A14  Elec     ACTB    Y  NaN
4   5   A15  Elec     CTBA    M  NaN
5   6   A16  Elec     CABA    Y  NaN
6   7   A17  Mech     CABA    Y  NaN
7   8   A18  Mech     CTBA    M    M
8   9   A19  Mech     ACTB    Y    Y
9  10   A20  Elec     CTBA    M  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks! It works fine for the example. However I have too many filtering operations, do you suggest any single liner for the above case?

Comment: It's a onliner if you see it properly.  I just split conditions m1 and m2 into variables for code readability ,  if you want put them inside the mask by replacing m1 and m2 by conditions .

Comment: Keep in mind, sometimes code readability is important than a one line solution.  It will not bug you in future.